# Pass complex object though intent

Tags: android

I need to pass a list of cookies from one activity to the other using an `Intent`. How would one go about achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Alot of similar questions here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another with Intent.putExtra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-with-intent-putextra)

Comment: @Alex: [Please also remove "please" and "thanks" from questions when editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) -- thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Intent.putExtra(String name, String[] value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) would be the easiest way to pass a list of cookies.  There are other putExtra signatures as well, depending on how you currently have your list implemented.  On the other side, you would use `getExtras()` to get values.  If for some reason, you had a more complex setup, you could create a `Cookie` class which extends `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it along in the `setExtra()` method of the `Intent` class.

Hope it helped,
JQCorreia

Comment: There is no corresponding function Intent.putExtra(Object) to achieve that.

Comment: @steve I prototype using Bundle b= new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("jalcomputing.confusetext.PasswordState", outState);
        i.putExtras(b); // intent i